# What is the mechanism of photo thermal heating in metal nanoparticles?

Tags: nanoscience

What are hot electrons?  What is the role of hot electrons in dephasing of excited surface plasmon ( in metal nano particles) via nonradiative decay which accounts for photo thermal heating? I'm not getting a complete picture of phothothermal heating mechanism in metal nanoparticles.